# use a RecyclerView to make a horizontal list view based off a customer list adapter Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am trying to make a horizontal scrolling view of pictures with a OnClick listener attached to each one that sends the user to a new webpage. I have done with very well with a vertical list, but now I want it to be horizontal. How can i do this. 
I have tried using a recyclerView like Android suggest, but I cannot get it to accept the adapter.

It gives me this error:
recycler view cannot be applied to CustomeListAdpater, as well as when I try to add a onClick it says it cannot resolve method setOnClickListern(anonymous android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener())

So here is what I have so far;

Here is the Linear layoutManager

```
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.promotionHolder);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

and here is where I assign the customer list adapter to the recycle view

```
 private void fillListView(ArrayList<ListItem> listData)
{
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, listData));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        //here is a method to either send the user to the poduct page
        //or to the main page in the app
        //open a new activity and close this one down
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            ListItem promoData = (ListItem) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //lest open up the corrisponding webpage
            Intent reDirect = new Intent();
            reDirect.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            reDirect.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            reDirect.setData(Uri.parse(promoData.getPathUrl()));
            String newUrl = Uri.parse(promoData.getPathUrl()).toString();
            if (newUrl.contains("http")) {
                startActivity(reDirect);
            } else {
                //if not do nothing
                Log.d("Path URL: ", " is null");
            }

        }
    });

    recyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, listData));
    recyclerView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        //here is a method to either send the user to the poduct page
        //or to the main page in the app
        //open a new activity and close this one down
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            ListItem promoData = (ListItem) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //lest open up the corrisponding webpage
            Intent reDirect = new Intent();
            reDirect.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            reDirect.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            reDirect.setData(Uri.parse(promoData.getPathUrl()));
            String newUrl = Uri.parse(promoData.getPathUrl()).toString();
            if (newUrl.contains("http")) {
                startActivity(reDirect);
            } else {
                //if not do nothing
                Log.d("Path URL: ", " is null");
            }

        }
    });
}
```

I kept the original Listview in there because it works fine as an example of what I was doing with this.

This is my xml file

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/promotionHolder"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layoutManager = "android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    >


</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

This is my Custom List Adapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter  extends BaseAdapter{
private ArrayList<ListItem> listData;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItem> listData) {
    this.listData = listData;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
        holder.labelView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ListItem newsItem = listData.get(position);
    //Check to see if there is a lable attached to the image
    if(newsItem.getLableTitle().equals("null"))
    {
        holder.labelView.setText("");

    }else
    {
        holder.labelView.setText(newsItem.getLableTitle());
    }

    if (holder.imageView != null) {
        new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getUrl());
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView labelView;
}
}
```

And this is the list_row_layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minHeight="8dp"
android:padding="1dp"
android:background="#000000"
>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#000000"

    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_below="@id/thumbImage"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="8pt"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RecyclerView does not provide `#setOnItemClickListener`, neither does `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

You should install the click listener within the Adapters `onBindViewHolder` method. Because I can not see any reference to that method above, I would think that your Adapter is not yet migrated to the new RecyclerView method.

You can refer to links on the internet, like https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/android-l-recyclerview-and-cardview-tutorial/156 for learning how to do this.

Comment: I am going to say your right and that I will have to redo everything from scratch. I don't think I can repurpose the project that I was using. Thank you very much

Comment: Switching to RecyclerView's **many** classes (`Adapter`, `ViewHolder` and so on) feels weird/complicated at first but later makes things super smooth. You don't want to go back. :-)